# Arcmap script will not print messages in arcmap console

Tags: python, arcgis, python-idle, arcpy, arcmap

I have a Python script for Arcmap that I wrote. I'm trying to create a tool that reprojects all the feature classes within the workspace to a specified feature class.

The problem that I'm having is that I cannot get Arcmap to print the "completed" messages. The messages that I want to have appear will print when I hard-code the variables and run it as a script, but they will not print in Arcmap. You can see in the code below that I have specific printed messages that I want printed, but they just won't appear.

Code:

```
#Import modules
import arcpy, os

#Set workspace directory
from arcpy import env

#Define workspace
inWorkspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
env.workspace = inWorkspace
env.overwriteOutput = True

try:
    #Define local feature class to reproject to:
    targetFeature = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

    #Describe the input feature class
    inFc = arcpy.Describe(targetFeature)
    sRef = inFc.spatialReference

    #Describe input feature class
    fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

    #Loop to re-define the feature classes and print the messages:
    for fc in fcList:
        desc = arcpy.Describe(fc)
        if desc.spatialReference.name != sRef.name:
            print "Projection of " + str(fc) + " is " + desc.spatialReference.name + ", so re-defining projection now:\n"
            newFc = arcpy.Project_management(fc, "projected_" + fc, sRef)
            newFeat = arcpy.Describe(newFc)
            count = arcpy.GetMessageCount()
            print "The reprojection of " + str(newFeat.baseName) + " " + arcpy.GetMessage(count-1) + "\n"

    #Find out which feature classes have been reprojected
    outFc = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("projected_*")

    #Print a custom messagae describing which feature classes were reprojected
    for fc in outFc:
        desc = arcpy.Describe(fc)
        name = desc.name
        name = name[:name.find(".")]
    name = name.split("_")
    name = name[1] + "_" + name[0]
    print "The new file that has been reprojected is named " + name + "\n"

except arcpy.ExecuteError:
    pass

severity = arcpy.GetMaxSeverity()

if severity == 2:
    print "Error occurred:\n{0}".format(arcpy.GetMessage(2))
elif severity == 1:
    print "Warning raised:\n{1}".format(arcpy.GetMessage(1))
else:
    print "Script complete"
```

When I upload a script into an Arcmap toolbox, the following lines (From the above code) will NOT print:

`print "Projection of " + str(fc) + " is " + desc.spatialReference.name + ", so re-defining projection now:\n"`

`print "The reprojection of " + str(newFeat.baseName) + " " + arcpy.GetMessage(count-1) + "\n"`

`print "The new file that has been reprojected is named " + name + "\n"`

How can I fix this?

Comment: I doubt that IDLE has anything to do with this, but to make sure, run your script directly with python, without involving IDLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print` only prints the messages while your script is running in Python interpreter. In order to print logs while the script is running in ArcGIS Toolbox, you need to use [`arcpy.AddMessage()`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/addmessage.htm)

```
arcpy.AddMessage("Projection of {0} is {1}, so re-defining projection now: ".format(str(fc), desc.spatialReference.name)
```